# Debian: What happens to /var/lib/<package> when a package gets updated?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, debian-based

Is it safe to keep data (such as uploaded files for a web application) in  /var/lib/`<package>`? Won't it get overwritten when the package gets updated?

OS: Ubuntu
The package installed via `apt-get install <package>`

Comment: Unix in general has no concept of a package manager.  This is apparently about Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg` does not overwrite files it did not install in the first place.

If you purge a package, everything marked as a config file will get removed; this is usually not done using a wildcard, so even then, files you installed outside of `dpkg` will probably be kept.

As to whether it is a good idea to keep uploads in `/var/lib` is questionable; something like `/var/cache` would seem less haphazard, but check the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for precise details.

Comment: Hmmm, no, not `/var/cache` either.

Comment: To me the `/var/cache/<package>` is temporary data so I would definitely not upload data there unless you want to first put it there and later move it to a more permanent location. The `/var/lib/<package>` is the usual location for changing data; for example MySQL or PostgreSQL place their data clusters at that location.